# jQuery AJAX request slow even though all previous requests aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have a search filter that fires an ajax request to update the result set upon changing filters. It often happens that the user will change many filters in one go, firing off many AJAX requests.

So I decided to abort previous requests if a new one is made (by using the ajax.abort() function). Now... Firebug shows all those requests as being aborted, but the last request (the only one not aborted) takes increasingly longer the more aborted requests before it.

So, for example, if I change just one filter, it'll take 1 second to load the request. But if I change 5 filters in one go, it aborts 4 of them, leaving only the last request. However, this request ends up taking 5 seconds to complete.

Anyone know why this is? I'm guessing that even though jQuery aborts the request, my server still processes it? (I'm running a local Rails Mongrel in development mode, fyi) That kinda defeats the whole reason why I aborted the requests... What can I do to solve this problem??

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the server isn't still processing those prior requests, and it's that side getting bogged down?

Comment: As Nick Craver alludes, cancelling the AJAX request will only destroy the handler for the callback - your page will ignore any incoming information. However, as soon as you send the AJAX request, the request has already been sent to the server for processing. However, unless your server has very high traffic or is very slow, this is unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: hmmm so i pushed it out onto my production server and it works just fine - i.e. it's not a problem because the server responds faster than i can click on the filters. like you said, only a problem with slow local development server. still, seems like there should be a better way of doing this (why should our server need to process unused requests?) maybe i'll try andy's answer with delayed request...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try an approach by delaying requests if the user's search parameters are being input rapidly. For example in one of my applications I wait until the user has stopped for a half second.

```
  $("#user_login").keypress(function() {
    var login = this;
    if (this.value != this.lastValue) {
      $("#loading_small").addClass("loading-small");
      if (this.timer) { clearTimeout(this.timer); }
      this.timer = setTimeout(function() { 
        $.get("/users/login_validate", $(login).serialize(), function(data) {
          $("#loading_small").removeClass("loading-small");
          $("#login_valid").fadeIn().html(data);
        });
      }, 500);
    }
  });
```

Comment: sounds like a good solution. in my mind more of a hack though... i feel like there should be a way to tell the server to stop processing those requests... but i'm guessing there isn't. a bunch of useless requests surely leads to scaling issues?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call it a hack - it's basically "wait for the user to stop typing for half a second (or however long you like) before making a request." I'd prefer this to sending even more requests to the server telling it to cancel old requests.